# Student TV channel - embedding YouTube videos

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, files

As you can guess from the title, I'm the new webmaster for a student TV channel and I need to update the site.

The site needs to pull in YouTube videos from a channel, embed the video player and display a brief description of the video, along with information about the cast & crew involved in the production.

I'm using Drupal 7, and have tried various YouTube modules (Media_YouTube, YouTube feeds importer, YouTube Pull, YouTube field) and haven't had success with any - some just put the URL as text in the node, others haven't pulled in the videos at all. It hasn't been a pleasant experience :(

Can anyone recommend a module which will allow me to create a node for every video on the YouTube channel? It would have to be able to mass-import the videos as theres ~500 on the channel at the moment and I *really* don't want to have to import them manually... Ideally it would periodically check for updates, but that isn't crucial if I can manually add them after the import.

Edit - This has been broken into two questions as suggested by a comment below. See [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51243/student-tv-channel-taxonomising-youtube-videos) for the other part.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello jackweirdy, welcome to DA! Could you please break your question down into two separate ones? I don't want to answer both here, and don't know which one of the two to address.

Comment: I've done that now, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51243/student-tv-channel-taxonomising-youtube-videos

Comment: what was the issue with youtube feed importer? I'm browsing around and find that this should be a simply solution to what you are looking for. also, was "feeds" module setup correctly?

Comment: It created a node for every video, but just put the YouTube extension there (IE watch?v=rgrirrg) instead of embedding the video with the youtube player. I'm pretty sure I set up feeds correctly, but since it's the first time I've done it I can't say for certain.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue - embedding YouTube videos taken in from a feed. LIke jackweirdy, I've tried the various modules (Media_YouTube, YouTube feeds importer, YouTube Pull, YouTube field) with the same level of success - some just put the URL as text in the node, others haven't pulled in at all. And like you, I have not had a pleasant experience.

Comment: The youtube_feeds_importer module is a bit buggy with some of the mappings not set up properly. I have this working on a site but had to alter the youtube_feeds_importer module quite a bit. You should have no problem with the youtube_field module as I am also using that. What is the youtube feed url you are using? Are you using rss1, rss2 or atom url?

Comment: See also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/79566/10086