# Student TV channel - taxonomising YouTube videos

Tags: taxonomy-terms, files

This question has been created to break up a previous question; see [there](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51143/student-tv-channel-embedding-youtube-videos) for more detail.

As you can guess from the title, I'm the new webmaster for a student TV channel and I need to update the site.

The site needs to pull in YouTube videos from a channel, embed the video player and display a brief description of the video, along with information about the cast & crew involved in the production. Similar videos (such as those in a series) need to be linked together in a "playlist" style, while other videos should be browsable through a gallery based on genre.

Does anyone know what the most effective way to taxonomise these videos would be? I'm thinking of fields `genre` and `series` at the moment, but I don't know how I could list cast & crew members. (Videos need to be organised so you can quickly find all of the videos with a cast/crew member involved with)

Comment: The cast and crew are going to be a problem if they are just in the description on youtube. You may have to use regular expressions to extract them out of the description string.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using series and genre as the main taxonomies as you've said and then using Tags to generate a taxonomy for cast and crew.

You can use the [Taxonomy Manager](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager/) module to bulk add and edit taxonomies, including tags.