# I want to import my youtube videos to drupal when I upload a video in YouTube

Tags: entities, files

It will sound stupid but what I want to do is I want to get YouTube videos to my drupal installation.

The challenge is one of my clients he wants to see if he can do like while he is walking and liked the video he can upload it somewhere(preferably YouTube) and it comes up in Drupal as field of node.

Is this possible in Drupal ? I am using version 7.

Comment: Do you have a problem with embedding videos to Drupal nodes? Or do you want Drupal to connect to youtube and send the file?

Comment: Check out the mediafront module. It comes with a feature that uses feeds to pull videos from a youtube channel.

Comment: I don't have issue embedding but it's more of integration like syncing with YouTube.

Answer (score 2):

[Social Content](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_content) module allows you to automatically import Youtube videos as nodes. It provides an easy-to-use graphical user interface where you can map node fields with the fields provided by the Youtube API.

To just display Youtube videos, you could map a [link](https://www.drupal.org/project/link) field to the Youtube Embed URL, and then output it with [Link iframe formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_iframe_formatter) module (for example).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this a little myself, and while I had to put it on hold in favor of other things, I do suggest reading up on the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/), which should allow you to create a new node every time you post a video on YouTube, as well as pull in the video information, which you could pass to fields in your video content type. (Obviously, you will need the [Media: YouTube](https://drupal.org/project/media_youtube) module.)

In short, I would think you would want to approach it something like this:

1. Set up an array in your site code to hold video info.
2. Set up a call to YouTube API, access your channel.
3. Use the API to determine the number of videos in your YouTube channel; if it is larger than the length of your array, add the most recent video to the array.
4. Step through the array and create a node for each key in the array (if it doesn't already exist).

If somebody out there knows a better method, I'd love to hear about it!

Good luck!

Comment: Sounds nice. Yeah but you are right time can be a constraint. Thanks for your comment. Definitely I will be developing module about it in few months if somebody hasn't started already.